# Jersey / REST Web Dynamic Application, Eclipse don't see changes

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I'm trying to implement a REST Webservice with JAX-RS.
However Eclipse don't see the changes that I made in my classes.

When I launch tomcat, everything is working fine. But when I get the path url to my webservice ("/trip"), it still displays my old method which was returning "Hello Jersey".

My class where I have my webservice :

```
package com.suptrip.ressourcesClass;

    @Path("/trip")
public class TripRessources {
      // This method is called if JSON request
      @GET
      @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
      public Trip getJSON() {
        Trip t= new Trip();
        t.setTitle("This is my first trip");
        t.setDescription("Lorem ipsum.");
        return t;
      }
}
```

My entity class used in the webservice :

```
package com.suptrip.entity;
@Entity
@Table(name="TRIP")
@XmlRootElement
public class Trip implements Serializable{
    ...properties, constructors, setters, getters etc.
}
```

My web.xml configuration for jersey :

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
         </servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.suptrip</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Previously I had a method in Trip.class like that :

```
  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }
```

I removed it but it still return "Hello Jersey".
Any idea ?

**What I tried :**
Restart Eclipse
Refresh Project
Clear server
Delete server / rebuild it

Answer (score 0):

Problem came from the jersey libraries in my web-content folder, remove them and add it from project properties > java build path